# Authorized.net Payment Getway Issue of transact.dll

Tags: php, wordpress, events, payment, authorize.net

I'm trying to implement Authorize.net Payment Getway in our site
And Start Test Mode in Authorized.net

But after Submit Payment Detail form
it goes to https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll link
And showing my website Content Without any image and stylesheet instead Goes to proper return path whichever i set in Authorized.net site

Is any one know what exactly happen this....

Comment: What API are you using? Are you using a plugin? Or did you write your own code?

Comment: I'm using Event registration plugin.

Comment: API URL:https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll